# Weeks and start day of the week and 53 weeks in a year

Tags: php

i'm lost a little bit. I have a statistic application that sum up sales totals of my employees for a range period of time. 
But here's my problem.
In my company, the year starts in july first.
But every weeks I give prize for the best sellers every Monday.
So in 2013 first of july started on moday, that was easy to calculate. So every 7 days I did the calculation in php.

But Now in 2014 the first of july is on tuesday. So if the person enter his sales on the monday 30 of june 2013, it's gonna be like the 53 weeks of the year 2013. 
I don't know how to correctly calculate all my stats, cause I want to start the year on july first, but on every monday I give prizes to my best sellers.

How to start let say on july first and then calculate the total amount of sales until the next monday and from now on every monday is the first day of the week.

tks
Seby

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you're doing or what you've done so it will be easier for us to understand what you're asking?

Comment: well for instance I want 7 of july 2014 to return week 2 and then every monday advance to 1 week further.

Comment: No one have any help for me?